# Is there any device or way to measure how many watts a computer's processor is using?

Tags: microprocessor, watts, power-measurement

I know there's a device to measure how many watts a computer is using, you get an energy meter you plug the computer into it and it tells you [image]

But I'm interested in finding out how many watts a processor uses.

Is there any device that can plug into a CPU socket as an intermediary and report it, and then that figure could be displayed on an LED or fed out on a wire and read by an arduino or raspberry pi.

Is it feasible and reasonably simple for such a device to be built?

e.g. just as one can measure how many volts a power supply rail is using, e.g. one can check that the red wire is 5V.. So too would it be simple to have a socket that is female one end and male another end and exposes its pins and then would a multimeter or some device connected to it be able to read off the power without interfering with what the processor is doing?

Processors do report TDP but that's a maximum. I'm interested in how many watts it runs at e.g. idling.

**added**  It has been pointed out to me that watts don't necessarily correlate with heat across processors e.g. an Intel Core i5 3230M is is based on 22nm, the cores are big.. Compared to a newer processor like a 7000u/8000u would be based on 14nm, and AMD's 4000 series is based on 7nm.  It's apparently perhaps a combination of small core and low watts that lead to low heat.

Comment: one could perhaps try a temperature measure with a temperature measuring gun but i'm interested specifically in the watts.

Comment: Does your motherboard report anything useful? Mine definitely reports VRM voltage, so that gets you half way there.

Comment: @JackB more of a general question really, not specific to any one motherboard

Comment: A general thing is probably going to be hard to do.  Modern motherboards have a VRM, that is a buck converter, very close to the CPU. To measure the actual power consumed by the CPU, you'd need to get at the PCB traces in that gap. Putting something on the 5V rail isn't enough, because that provides power to lots of other things too.

Comment: @JackB Forget the 5V rail!! (I only mentioned that as an analogy).  But perhaps a male to female "socket" seated between the processor and the actual socket.could potentially expose all pins of the CPU including any pins used for power, and thus measure watts, couldn't it? It surely could expose the volts, the problem is that you'd need a circuit to measure current and I've no idea how or if that'd be possible.  There are USB adaptors that can measure volts and amps of a USB port (called USB charge port).  So besides USB, why not for any device? (I don't mean measuring CPU watts via USB!).

Comment: @JackB I mean the concept of measuring through an intermediary M-F device. Like in the case of a device in a USB port,like USB charger doctor, you can measure the volts and current.(and thus power) of a USB device. In an analogous manner with a device that fits into a CPU socket it may be possible for that device to measure volts and current thus power.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some motherboards, especially laptops, have this as part of their sensor suite: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68531/return-value-of-current-watt-consumption-on-command-line.

Also, try OpenHardwareMonitor for Windows.

The power supply for a large CPU will usually be put through a switchmode converter right next to it on the motherboard, and that itself may be a microprocessor or dedicated IC. Given that these measure their output voltage and through current as part of their operation, that is the ideal point to take a measurement. Note that it may vary a lot from one microsecond to another depending on CPU load.

The power management systems will want to know the power consumption so they can adjust the fans, the CPU speed scaling and ACPI power state in order to achieve best performance without overheating.

Edit: a device that fits in the socket is called an "interposer", and looks like this. [image: LGA Interposer]

[Intel also sell them](https://designintools.intel.com/Socket_H2_LGA1155_Interposer_p/q6uj9a00081i.htm), although with a price listed as "build to order" that's going to be very expensive. The problem in building one is not disrupting any of the data signals.

Comment: Your link https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68531/return-value-of-current-watt-consumption-on-command-line  doesn't mention specifically power from the processor

Comment: Open Hardware Monitor works for two laptops/processors I just tried it on https://i.imgur.com/4gK8ArV.png  and https://i.imgur.com/EUZi8fW.png   though looking on google images I see  lots of examples where it doesn't

Comment: Yes, you're reliant on the manufacturer having included the sensors.

Comment: See edit re: interposer.